# How can i optimize this loop ? Python code with json

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I'm trying to run a script which is comparing two arrays extracted from some json. The script is working but it is not optimized at all. I would like a bit of help concerning the if conditions, I would like to know if there is a better way to do it (I'm 100% sure there is). Thanks you a lot for your help !

```py
def compare(id1, id2, nb):
    if id2 >= id1:
        return 1 - (id2 - id1) / nb
    else:
        return 1 - (id1 - id2) / nb

searchList = ['student', 'runner', 'fireman', 'chief', 'teacher', 'seller', 'fisher', 'policeman']

for e in searchList:

for id1, item1 in enumerate(data1[e]['items']):
    for id2, item2 in enumerate(data2[e]['items']):
        if e == 'runner':
            if item1['details']['profile_link'] == item2['details']['profile_link']:
                res += compare(id1, id2, nb)
        elif e == 'policeman' or e == 'products':
            if item1['title'] == item2['title']:
                res += compare(id1, id2, nb)
        elif e == 'fisher':
            if item1['description'] == item2['description']:
                res += compare(id1, id2, nb)
        elif e == 'chief':
            if item1['program']['one'] and item2['program']['one']:
                if item1['program']['one']['title'] == item1['program']['one']['title']:
                    res += compare(id1, id2, nb)
            elif item1['program']['two'] and item2['program']['two']:
                if item1['program']['two']['title'] == item1['program']['two']['title']:
                    res += compare(id1, id2, nb)
        else:
            if item1['profile_link'] == item2['profile_link']:
                res += compare(id1, id2, nb)

res = res * 1000
```

Thanks you a lot !

**Edit #1:**

Thanks for your help,

Here is an exemple of my json structure :

```
{
    "student": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "profile_link": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "runner": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "profile_link": "xxx"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "policeman": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "title": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "fisher": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "description": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "chief": {
            "count": 1,
            "items": {
                "program": {
                    "one": [
                        {
                            "index": 0,
                            "title": "xxx",
                        }
                    ],
                    "two": [
                        {
                            "index": 0,
                            "title": "xxx",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
    },
    "fireman": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "profile_link": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "teacher": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "profile_link": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "seller": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "profile_link": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post sample values of `data1` and `data2`, and provide some details on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You compare function should be a single line:  `return 1 - abs(id1 - id2) / nb`

Answer (score 0):

The biggest inefficiency here is the `O(n*m)` runtime complexity where n is the number of data1 items and m is the number of items in data2. You can change this to `O(n+m)` by filling a hashmap with all items of data1 and then directly getting all equal elements for data2.

Try this:

```
# Runner
data1_items_by_key = {}
for id1, item1 in enumerate(data1['runner']['items']):
    key = item1['details']['profile_link']
    if key not in data1_items_by_key:
        data1_items_by_key[key] = []
    data1_items_by_key[key].append(item1)
for id2, item2 in enumerate(data2['runner']['items']):
    key = item2['details']['profile_link']
    for item1 in data1_items_by_key.get(key, []):
        res += compare(id1, id2, nb)

# Policeman
data1_items_by_key = {}
for id1, item1 in enumerate(data1['policeman']['items']):
    key = item1['title']
    if key not in data1_items_by_key:
        data1_items_by_key[key] = []
    data1_items_by_key[key].append(item1)
for id2, item2 in enumerate(data2['policeman']['items']):
    key = item2['title']
    for item1 in data1_items_by_key.get(key, []):
        res += compare(id1, id2, nb)
```

Comment: I would like to avoid redundancy that's why I made it this way even if the complexity is not the best. I want my code to be easy to read and undertsand but thanks for your answer !